# attempting to deploy meteor application. Fails when running NPM INSTALL

Tags: node.js, npm, meteor

Sorry for the following wall of text.

So I've been using someone else's meteor app. (they open sourced it) It's currently un-built and I've been running it on dev-mode. It's a lot slower than expected and users are having issues connecting to my local machine. So I'm attempting to deploy the app by following: https://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html#deploying.

So I've been getting errors when trying to run `npm i`. My dad recommended me to run `npm cache verify` and try again, then `npm cache clean` as a last resort. Neither worked and I've still am getting errors. Although as soon as I tried again after running `npm cache verify` the error amount skyrocketed. I unfortunately don't have the errors I got *before* I cleared my cache but I have the current logs here: https://pastebin.com/dAcRnE9v But here is a snapshot:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! fibers@2.0.2 install: `node build.js || nodejs build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@2.0.2 install script.
```

I honestly don't have any idea what todo. I've never worked with meteor before, nor the fibers module that's failing. I don't even know if this is the right place I should be asking for help.

Comment: Do you use a tool like `mup`, do you deploy to Galaxy or your own server? If you use `mup` please add your anonymized `mup.js` config, if you manually deploy, please add all the involved steps. Deployment is a complex multistep process and errors can sneak in everywhere.

Comment: What version of meteor is the app running? You should always run `meteor npm install` to make sure that it uses the correct version of npm/node for installing libraries. I agree with @Jankapunkt - using mup is pretty easy, and recommended, even on an internal server. What is the github url for the repo?

Comment: @Jankapunkt  no I don't use mup. But i'll look it up rn and see what I can do w/ it.

@Mikkel Meteor 1.10.1 And yea I've ran `meteor npm install` before I did the cache clean. Just ran `meteor npm install` with the same results even though I verifyed the cache and deleted the `node_modules` folder. Repo: https://github.com/ThaumRystra/DiceCloud

Comment: If you have a custom deployment then you need to make sure, that the node version matches the node version of your meteor project, check `meteor node -v` also there can be multiple node bins on the server like `node` and `nodejs` there must be some older answer on this whole deployment topic where I covered this issue in depth

Comment: my `meteor node -v` is 12.16.1 while my `node -v` is 13.12.0. I'mma try to update meteor's node and get back to you with whether it continues to fail.

Comment: Downgraded my node to `12.16.1` re-installed the modules via `meteor npm install` then built the app via `meteor build <path>` then ran `npm install` and am getting the same error as before.

Comment: Looked at mup, attempted to use it. Got some issues when trying to `mup setup` it to my local machine, made a issue here: https://github.com/zodern/meteor-up/issues/1141

Comment: Can you try with yarn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once had `fibers` npm package in my package.json which caused a similar error. Once I removed it everything built just fine.

Comment: Well that fixed it, I had to remove the `fibers` module from the package.json inside the app before I built it and AGAIN after I built it, then manually run `npm i fibers` just to get it working. TY!

Comment: I would recommend removing fibers all together, instead of fibers use promises.

Comment: This isn't actually my app, I'm running https://github.com/ThaumRystra/DiceCloud on my local machine so my players can access it offline.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change Meteor's version of node - for compatibility reasons it bundles node/npm with Meteor to protect you. Just prefix all your npm/node commands with `meteor` like this:

`meteor npm install`

It won't use the node version (13.x) that you have installed

Comment: I know this now. I've downgraded my node to Meteor's node v. Had a busy day and today I'm rebuilding the meteor app so I can try to deploy it again. But nonetheless I did use `meteor npm install` which threw the error in my question.
I'll find out l8r today if it throws a diff error or succed, now that my node's v is different.